# Frozen water cooler bottle

Tags: soft-question

My water bottle for my water cooler is frozen.  Should I place it onto the water cooler while it is frozen, wait till it thaws a bit, or wait till it thaws completely?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about physics.

Comment: you should be free to do whatever you want, as far as it does not harm anyone. Now, if you had a specific goal (such as unfroze it faster), you might get a specific answer

Comment: Maybe the question has something to do with physics, but I agree with Bruce that the question is a bit vague because it doesn't state what the poster's goal is.